# Filtering rows of a 2D String matrix by string value

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq, jagged-arrays

So I have a 2D Array defined as `String[][] data_set_examples` which holds the following data:

```
Sunny,Hot,High,Weak,No
Sunny,Hot,High,Strong,No
Overcast,Hot,High,Weak,Yes
Rain,Mild,High,Weak,Yes
Rain,Cool,Normal,Weak,Yes
...
```

I would like to filter rows by a particular value, for example rows containing "Hot" (by column index 1)

I understand that one possibility might be by using LINQ. While I am not familiar, I have tried the following, however no filtering is being done.

```
var result = from u in data_set_examples
                         where u[column_index].Equals(attribute_value)
                         select u;
```

what am I doing wrong? and is there an alternative method?

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you sure the `column_index` is correct? Have you tried setting a breakpoint and inspecting the data in `data_set_examples` to make sure it is what you think is it?

Comment: How you prove this : "however no filtering is being done"?

Comment: Why not just create a class, that holds the data, what currently a matrix row holds, and create a List or any IEnumerable from that? This is absolutely anti-object-oriented. It would be much easier to filter, transform etc.

Comment: how i'm checking:

foreach (string[] s in result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(s);
            }

Comment: the problem is in you checking, check with this one and see the result `foreach (string[] s in result) { Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", s)); } `

Comment: you're right, that was the problem @dotctor it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks fine, I think the problem is in your way of checking your filtering result.

When you uses

```
foreach (string[] s in result) 
{ 
    Console.WriteLine(s); 
}
```

you are just writing type name of `string[]`

however you should see inside those `string[]` which are inside your result (`string[][]`)

you can do this in two way

```
foreach (string[] s in result)
{
     //concatenate all the values in s
     Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", s));
}
```

or

```
foreach (string[] s in result)
{
    //iterate through strings in s and print them
    foreach (string s1 in s)
    {
        Console.Write(s1 + " ");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: Ok great, thanks for pointing that out. that was the problem. it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I have tried this, and just confirmed it works:

```
 string[][] data_set_examples = new string[][]{
                new string[]{"Sunny", "Hot", "High", "Weak", "No"},
                new string[]{"Sunny", "Hot", "High", "Strong", "No"},
                new string[]{"Overcast", "Hot", "High", "Weak", "Yes"},
                new string[]{"Rain", "Mild", "High", "Weak", "Yes"},
                new string[]{"Rain", "Cool", "Normal", "Weak", "Yes"},
            };
            IEnumerable<string[]> result = from u in data_set_examples
                         where u[1].Equals("Hot")
                         select u;
            foreach (string[] s in result) {
                foreach (string part in s)
                    Console.Write(part + " ");
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
            Console.Read();
```

Producing the output:

```
Sunny Hot High Weak No
Sunny Hot High Strong No
Overcast Hot High Weak Yes
```